# ParseデータをPFQueryTableViewControllerのcustom cellに表示したい

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse.com

PFQueryTableViewControllerのサブクラスを作りLabelをoutlet接続してParseのデータをLabelに表示しようとしていますが上手くいきません。
Parseチュートリアルや英語stackoverflowを読んでも解決できませんでした。
どなたか回答宜しくお願いします。
cell.textLabel.textやcell.detailTextLabel.textなどを使うのではなくUILabelを使ってセルの任意の場所にParseのデータを表示したいのです。

コンソールには[PFTableViewCell postLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instanceと出ます。

- AppDelegate.mではアプリ固有のIDとclientKeyを指定しています。
- storyboardでCellのClassにMyTableCellを指定しています。

MyTableCell.h

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@interface MyTableCell : PFTableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *postLabel;
@end
```

MyPFQueryTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@interface MyPFQueryTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController
@end
```

MyPFQueryTableViewController.m

```
#import "MyPFQueryTableViewController.h"  
#import "MyTableCell.h"  
@interface MyPFQueryTableViewController ()  
@end  
@implementation MyPFQueryTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {   
    NSLog(@"%s",\__func__);  
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];  
    if (self) {  
        self.parseClassName = @"UserPost";  
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;  
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;  
        self.objectsPerPage = 25;  
    }  
    return self;  
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {  
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];  
    if (self.pullToRefreshEnabled) {  
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;  
    }  
    if (self.objects.count == 0) {  
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;  
    }  
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];  
    return query;  
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {  
    NSLog(@"%s",\__func__);  
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  
    PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
    if (cell == nil) {  
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
    }  
    MyTableCell *PostCell = nil;  
    PostCell = (MyTableCell *)cell;  
    NSString *PostText = [object objectForKey:@"PostText"];   
    PostCell.postLabel.text = PostText;  
    return cell;  
 }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];  
}  

@end
```

Comment: @Yoshii さん、@Tomohiro Obara さん、@Ken さん遅ればせながらご回答ありがとうございます。  Yoshiiさん、ラベルの設置と接続は間違えてなかったです。  
Tomohiro Obaraさん、cell.textLabel.textやcell.detailTextLabel.textは利用できます。  UITableViewControllerとUITableViewCellを使ってカスタムセルを作るのは実現できてるのですが、PFQueryTableViewControllerとPFTableViewCellだと実現できません。  　
Kenさん、ご回答のしていただいたように初めからMyTableCellでcellを使ってセルを作るコードを使ってみました。　　
それでもラベルに文字が表示されません。　　
NSLog(@"cell=%@",cell.postLabel.text);は
cell=(null)と出てしまいます。　　
"PostText"のParseのデータは文字データが入っています。　　
あとxcodeのDebug View Hierarchyで見てみるとMyPFTableCellの上にUITableViewCellContentViewがあって、その上にラベルが見当たりません。　　
ご回答お願いします！

Comment: 問題解決できました！ストーリボードで作る場合、初期化をinitWithStyleではなくinitWithCoderを使えば上手く動きました。基本的な事がどうやらわかっていなかったみたいです。http://qiita.com/EntreGulss/items/48a4100dd5fac248d145こちらの記事が問題解決に繋がりました。回答してくださった皆様どうもありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PFTableViewCell` ではなく、 `MyTableCell` のインスタンスを生成してみてください。

つまり、

誤: `cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:...`

正: `cell = [[MyTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:...`

です。

エラーの原因は、 `PFTableViewCell` のインスタンスなので、 `postLabel` プロパティが存在しないためです。

`-[tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` の中を、下記のようにしてみてください。

```
MyTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];  
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[MyTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
cell.postLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"PostText"];
return cell;
```

Answer (score 1):

カスタムセルの実現方法が間違っていると想像します。

PostCell = (MyTableCell *)cell;
単に型変換でMyTableCellのインスタンスを取得できているように思えません。

まず、「cell.textLabel.textやcell.detailTextLabel.text」を利用してうまくいっているかを確認
その後にカスタムセルを利用して「UILabelを使ってセルの任意の場所にParseのデータを表示」を実現
というステップで進めると良いと思います。
あるいは、カスタムセルの実現を個別に確認した上でParseと組み合わせるとか。

Answer (score 1):

story board側でMyTableCellを指定しているセル内にラベルを設置していますか？

そのセルを「IBOutlet UILabel *postLabel;」と接続していますか？

「unrecognized selector sent to instance」が出るときには表示された値のインスタンスを実体化できていないときだと思いますので、おそらく上記の内容あたりが原因ではないでしょうか？